# use the result data from a function to another SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with functions in a package. The problem is that i got
two functions. The first function we can call it "function_a". The result from this function, how can I send it over in the function_b? What are the command to pass the result over to function_b?

The code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_PKG AS
FUNCTION F_a  (F_h NUMBER,   F_r NUMBER ) RETURN  NUMBER
AS
V_PI NUMBER := 3.14;
V_BOTTEN NUMBER := F_r * F_r * V_PI;
V_VOLYM NUMBER;
BEGIN
V_VOLYM := F_h * V_BOTTEN;
RETURN V_VOLYM;
END F_a;

FUNCTION_B
.....
....
....
```

How can i get the result from v_volym in function_a to function_B?

Comment: Just create a variable in function_b that store the result of function_a.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Thats the problem, i do not really how to store the result of the function_a in to function_b in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_PKG AS
FUNCTION F_a (F_h NUMBER, F_r NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER
AS
V_PI NUMBER := 3.14;
V_BOTTEN NUMBER := F_r * F_r * V_PI;
V_VOLYM NUMBER;
BEGIN
V_VOLYM := F_h * V_BOTTEN;
RETURN V_VOLYM;
END F_a;

FUNCTION F_b RETURN NUMBER
AS
F_A_RESULT NUMBER;
BEGIN
F_A_RESULT := F_A(1,2);
RETURN F_A_RESULT;
END F_B;

PROCEDURE P_b (RESULT OUT NUMBER) 
AS

BEGIN
RESULT := F_A(1,2);
END F_B;
....
```

Comment: Thank you it worked Aramillo! can i do the same with procedures to?

Comment: Yes @RobertMartinsson you can, it is a little different, in that case you need to use output variables.

Comment: I add the procedure example

Comment: I have a problem i dont now why really.. i got one procedure with two in parameters. In function A i have done the math input1 + input2 and so on. When in function B i call the procedure_a(2,2); but it dont work.. do i need two output parameters in function b?

Answer (score -2):

Use Package variables. They will have scope across the package.

Comment: Please do not just link documentation. Answer the OPs question with detail and examples.

Comment: Hi Feby, welcome to SO. Please read [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), specifically the last section about self-promotion. You have included that link in several answers and although it looks like your answers are genuine, this makes them resemble spam. Adding "signatures" at the end of answers is strongly discouraged here. You can talk about this website in the "About me" section of your profile, or [see this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising) for information about advertising your site with SO.